# How to execute part of the code under certain conditions JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I add

```
var registry = require('uiRegistry');
var component = registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street.0'); 

component.value(window.checkoutConfig.customer_address['street']);
```

But `component` is null.
I came up with a solution:

```
var timerId = setInterval(function setAddress() {
                var registry = require('uiRegistry');
                if(registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street.0')!=null) {
                    var component = registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street.0');
                    component.value(window.checkoutConfig.customer_address['street']);
                    clearInterval(timerId);
                }
            },2000);
```

But I think, that it is a bad solution. May be jQuery has any event like ready? For example when  `registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street.0')!=null` then starts executing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, jquery has a `ready` event. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @peeebeee it's working just for DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
require('uiRegistry', function(registry){
       var component = registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping- 
       step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street.0'); 
       if(component){
         component.value(window.checkoutConfig.customer_address['street']);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this ->

```
registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street.0', (value) => { });
```

May be this work? you can make use of the value and do the your work

Comment: It's ok, but It's just set ' ', and I need to get value when it set